QGIS Set Project Colors via Python
since we try to automate QGIS related project settings, I am currently struggling with setting project colors in the project properties usinq PyQGIS.
I managed to retrieve any existing color scheme:
project_color_scheme = qgis.core.QgsColorScheme()
for color in project_color_scheme.fetchColors():
   print(color)

For what I found out is that the method "setProjectColors" accepts an iterable to set a color scheme. But I am out of ideas how to form it.

Unfortunately, I did not manage to find any examples so far and as QGIS Python API lacks any examples.
How I solve this?

You can add the project colors using the setProjectColors method of QgsProject. The method takes a list of tuples, each of which consists of a QColor and a name.
from qgis.core import QgsProject
from PyQt5.QtGui import QColor

# define project colors as list of tuples
color1 = (QColor(100, 100, 100), 'color1')
color2 = (QColor(200, 200, 200, 100), 'color2')
colors = [color1, color2]

# set project colors
QgsProject.instance().setProjectColors(colors)

The resulting project colors:

